# values_list does not use to_python in custom model fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I seem to have stumbled across a quirk in Django custom model fields.  I have the following custom modelfield:

```
class PriceField(models.DecimalField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return Price(super(PriceField, self).to_python(value))
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            return None

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        return super(PriceField, self).get_db_prep_value(value.d if value else value)

    def value_to_string(self, instance):
        return 'blah'
```

Which should always return the custom Price class in python.  This works as expected:

```
>>> PricePoint.objects.all()[0].price
Price('1.00')
```

However when retrieving prices in the form of a values_list I get decimals back:

```
>>> PricePoint.objects.all().values_list('price')
[(Decimal('1'),)]
```

Then if I change the DB type to foat and try again I get a float:

```
>>> PricePoint.objects.all().values_list('price')
[(1.0,)]
>>> type(PricePoint.objects.all().values_list('price')[0][0])
<type 'float'>
```

This makes me think that values_list does not rely on to_python at all and instead just returns the type as defined in the database.  Is that correct?  Is there any way to return a custom type through values_list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question: This apparently is a Django bug.  values_list does not deserialize the database data.

It's being tracked here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9619 and is pending a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that this was resolved in Django 1.8 with the addition of the `from_db_value` method on custom fields.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects